# Fatal Error :Can't open realm

Tags: ios, swift, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I am working on IOS. I am using **realm** database in the frontend. It was working fine until I made some changes to the realm model and all files related to it. I just added one field to these files.

Now I am getting an error **"Fatal error: Can't open realm"** in the following code

```
fileprivate func getRealm() -> Realm {
    // get default configuration realm
    do {
        return try Realm()
    } catch {
        Swift.fatalError("Can't open realm")  //Fatal Error :Can't open realm
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell what might be the possible causes for this error.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you made changes to the realm model, you need to increase your schema version and you may or may need to provide a migration block. [See](https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest#migrations) the official documentation for details.

```
// Inside your [AppDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:]

RLMRealmConfiguration *config = [RLMRealmConfiguration defaultConfiguration];
// Set the new schema version. This must be greater than the previously used
// version (if you've never set a schema version before, the version is 0).
config.schemaVersion = 1;

// Set the block which will be called automatically when opening a Realm with a
// schema version lower than the one set above
config.migrationBlock = ^(RLMMigration *migration, uint64_t oldSchemaVersion) {
    // We haven’t migrated anything yet, so oldSchemaVersion == 0
    if (oldSchemaVersion < 1) {
        // Nothing to do!
        // Realm will automatically detect new properties and removed properties
        // And will update the schema on disk automatically
    }
};

// Tell Realm to use this new configuration object for the default Realm
[RLMRealmConfiguration setDefaultConfiguration:config];

// Now that we've told Realm how to handle the schema change, opening the file
// will automatically perform the migration
[RLMRealm defaultRealm];
```

Comment: Ok Thanks! will check

Answer (score 0):

The above issue is caused due to inconsistency in the Realm database. I changed the structure of the model by adding one field. So, the model was having 10 fields but the realm database in my app was having 9 fields, as the app was built before the changes.

I solved the issue by just reinstalling the app which regenerated the realm database in the phone, thereby having a consistent model and database.

The above workaround might be good if your app is yet to be live. But, if your app is already being used by other users, then they will have to reinstall the app on update, which might result in bad user experience for the user.

Ideally, you should be writing a migration block for the new changes.
Hope, this is clear to all.